# How can I get a website to completely refresh?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

At the moment I'm only experiencing the problem at "http://support.google.com/". The website looks like it has no CSS applied. (Blue links, times new roman). I have the Pendule extention installed and I've tried refreshing the websites CSS. I've tried opening the page in another browser (IE) where it works perfectly.

I'm using Google Chrome, Windows 7, and I've tried clearing cache, browsing history and cookies. I've searched around, but I can't quite understand what has happened.

Any ideas?

Comment: The command to force a refresh is `CTRL-F5` always has been.

Answer (score 2):

To force refresh most browsers, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. However, I have a feeling that just refreshing the website won't solve your situation. Have you tried restarting the browser? Can you perhaps post a screenshot of what it looks like?

Comment: In IE: http://i48.tinypic.com/i1xhms.jpg, in Chrome: http://i50.tinypic.com/2ylvjup.jpg

Comment: What does Chrome look like with all extensions disabled?

Comment: It looks the same, I've also tried using Incognito-mode to disable extentions, and using default settings. Looks the same.

Comment: Have you restarted your computer?

Comment: Yes I have restarted my computer. :)

Comment: Grr. Now *I'm* annoyed with your computer ;) What happens if you boot in safe mode?

Comment: Do you see any errors on the JavaScript console? (Ctrl+Shift+J)

Comment: Yeah, loads of errors.. http://i45.tinypic.com/2v0d6yc.jpg There is an "all.css" error there. Hm.